# is it possible to handle all exception in javascript so that no error display in console of browser?

Tags: javascript, error-handling

I know about the window.onerror event that triggers when exception occurs, so it works as a notifier as still we will get the error message in console.

What i want is that to display the custom message when the exception occur in application and get rid of all console **red** error messages.

Is there any way? using try catch in application is painfull though.

Answer (score 2):

If you `return true` at the end of the `onerror` handler, the default handling (like printing to the console) should be skipped. Then, of course, you can do any custom handling you'd like.

There's some good documentation for the handler [on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onerror).